# Go newbie: Getting "mismatched types *int and int" error when trying to compare reference to static integer

Tags: go

I'm learning Go and trying to use reference to integer value in if-clause.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := 19
    b := &a
    if b > 10 {
        fmt.Println("Its bigger")
    }

}
```

This gives error message for type mismath. 
How could I successfully compare value which `b` is referencing. In my training code I'm reading command line arguments with flags, but I suppose this example is reprex.

How should I compare when havin only reference available?

Comment: You need to dereference the pointer to get to the value, and then you can compare it. e.g. `if *b > 10 {`. (Note that `*` in `*v` and `*T` where `v` is a value and `T` is a type does not denote the same thing, in `*v` the `*` is an operator for dereferencing a pointer, while in `*T` the `*` designates a pointer type.)

Comment: Thanks. This is what i was looking for!

Comment: A `*int` is **not** a "reference" to int. There are no references in Go and it is not helpful to think of pointers as "references" as you noticed. Pointers are pointers and are distinct types and non-nil pointers point to variables and nothing here is a reference. Do yourself a favor an stop thinking of pointers as "references": They are not.

Comment: Hmm.. This question has been given two downvotes. Could someone explain why. I really tried to follow quidelines by providing simple example code and trying to resolve the problem before asking it here. It sure is a simple newbie question, but that shouldn't be a problem, should it?

Comment: A downvote doesn't mean you did a bad job it just means the question is not an interesting or probably relevant one.

Comment: Yep, it's probably that. I've always been thinking that you should give downvotes for questions which violates site guidelines or are out of Stack Overflows scope. And it's funny that all very useful responses given here has gain upvotes. But at least I got my answer I was looking for in minutes. So I can keep on looking at new language. More than 10 years of Python coding and you'll forget everything about pointers :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `b` is a pointer of `int` means `*int`. You can't compare `*int` type with `int` type.

Use `*b` to dereference to get the value and then compare with constant value.

```
if *b > 10 {
        fmt.Println("Its bigger")
}
```